# FeedRequest not working. "An Error Has Occured, please try again later"

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

I have the facebook SDK (Beta 5.04) integrated in my Unity project (Unity 4.3).

I have the application in Google Play in Draft mode, and the application in facebook live (with the correct information in the Android Tab).

I can log in into the application without a problem, but when I go to do a FB.Feed, I get the messsage "An Error has occured, please try again later".

I looked at the Unity logcat, and it was clear of erros. Then I looked at the FB logcat, and also there are no errors shown:

```
D/FBUnitySDK(15812): KeyHash: iam0M6B6i+l9GpfclIQtL0jX/8M=
V/FBUnitySDK(15812): sending to Unity OnInitComplete({"key_hash":"iam0M6B6i+l9Gp
fclIQtL0jX\/8M=\n","user_id":"749888136","expiration_timestamp":"1398794624","ac
cess_token":"CAADUXWeAMigBAJVXzZBdfjhnl7pG4udmQji7WcJi3Qo9KfZCoaPjyMXBJFWv4kDjA7
nbQPv9eZAathIuZCLlUHv6u5feTLsHDgHhsqpLBy8M3Ni6yYk3pj2ZC07yToJZCsu1hHaEiceZAoW1GB
ZAaGI7xXgzK96ATWy3hlOBXqD0xtXyhfFPNxaZBwaTyLrb3EsUPf1uoDyxmiSbJ4dyXUp204QIV772zy
avDCXXZCUn7sHAZDZD","opened":true})
V/FBUnitySDK(15812): FeedRequest({"link":"https://play.google.com/store/apps/det
ails?id=com.webdots.sugarhero","name":"Sugar Hero","caption":"Play Sugar Hero! I
f you have the highest score, you could win $500!","picture":"https://lh4.ggpht.
com/ZLrj3DMU2dpPNIdMfqxeeIeTc1LDxPEDtb8CUleG1oln_NoMzVSFvJQPxfR8P9iCPw=w300-rw"}
```

Im stuck, and I dont know what to do. Any help if appretiated

Comment: Where do you see that error?

Comment: When I click on my button to post on facebook wall, the facebook dialog window opens, and I only see that error message

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug on our side, we will try to fix it as soon as possible.

If your link contains dots in get params, feed will fail.

One of the temporary workarounds is to use url shortener.